# Which is the best way to install aircrack-ng suit

Tags: apt, wget, aircrack-ng

I have seen two ways to install aircrack-ng in ubuntu

Way 1: installing -build-essential,libssl-dev,...,make,make install

Way 2: sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng

Which of the ways to prefer and why?

Comment: Which of the ways to prefer? Only you can say.

Comment: This is primarily an opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way 1 (install from source): you can get the latest version, but you have to resolve all the dependencies manually and you have to compile and to install the executables yourself; this can be an hassle even for an experienced user, since you have to resolve *all of the dependencies* manually (although if you're lucky and at least part of the dependencies for the `aircrack-ng` version present in the repositories meet the requirements of the `aircrack-ng` version to be installed this can be either alleviated or solved for good by using `apt-get build-dep aircrack-ng`); not to mention that uninstalling will require to go through the inverse procedure;

Way 2 (install from repository): you usually don't get the latest version, however it's a matter of running a single command and everything will Just Work™; not to mention that uninstalling it's still a matter of running a single command.

So it's really up to you: if having the latest version for whatever reason is worth the hassle (hassle to be evaluated mostly in the perspective of the time to be spended in order to resolve the dependencies, and in the perspective of the time to be spended in order to eventually possibly uninstall it) then install it from the source; otherwise just install it from the repository.

Comment: Easier uninstall shoul be mentioned for apt installations.

Comment: @Pilot6 I agree, I added that to the explanation